# Searching in .txt file that contains class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I am very new to C# (only experience with programming was with Haskell and a bit of C) and I was tasked with learning this language by myself and doing a project using it.

So, what I pretend to do is to use user input (an AccessKey) as a way to locate which Tech is login in by comparing between AccessKeys in a .txt (that only contains this class, Tech) and then return the TechID and TechName associated with the inserted AccessKey.

```
class Tech
{
    public String TechName
    { get; set; }
    public String TechID
    { get; set; }
    public String AccessKey
    { get; set; }
    public Tech(String TechNames, String TechIDs, String AccessKeys) 
    {
        TechName = TechNames;
        TechID = TechIDs;
        AccessKey = AccessKeys;
    }
}   


class Registo
{
    public List<Tech> ListaTech
    { get; set; }
    public Registo()
    {
        ListaTech = new List<Tech>();
    }
    public void addTech(Tech tech)
    {
        ListaTech.Add(tech);
    }
}
```

This are the classes that I am using, and following is the code responsible for updating the .txt file

```
    private void saveRegistry(string v, Tech tech)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Registo registo;

       using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\\Registry.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            registo = (Registo)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            registo.addTech(tech);

        }
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\\Registry.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, registo);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

at the button click is what is below:

```
        string pastaMae = "C:\\";
        string directoryName = pastaMae;
        string fileName = "Registry.txt";

        string techNames = textBoxRegisto1.Text;
        string techIDs = textBoxRegisto2.Text;
        string AccessKeys = textBoxRegisto3.Text;
        Tech tech = new Tech(techNames, techIDs, AccessKeys);

        try
        {
            // This line creates the directory using the path that was just created
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

            saveRegistry(pastaMae + fileName, tech);

        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e2.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

What I can't do (and need help with) is to create a function to compare the user input with the AccessKeys on the file and then to return the TechID and TechName that is associated with it.

Something that maybe would start like this?

```
    public Tech getTech(String AcessKey)
    {

    }
```

I think this code explains what happens much better than me, but if you need any more code or for me to explain in a different way I will try my best. Sorry for my lack of use of better and proper terms, as I said I am pretty new to C#.

Comment: A couple of questions: why are the parameter names for your `Tech` constructor plural nouns (`TechNames`, etc.)? Why are you using a binary formatter to save/read text information? Have you considered a format like JSON? It would make your debugging easier. If it were me, I'd keep everything in a `Dictionary<string, Tech>` and use a JSON serializer

Comment: For no particular reason, I thought I could name them anything I just add 's' in front of all 3.

I can't really answer that well, my knowledge equals 0. I just tried out this way until it worked.
I am not aware of JSON formatting, what sections of code that I should would I have to change? Just the classes?
Thank you for your input!

Comment: I just want to add that I have almost no theoric basis and this project is the first code I am writing in C#, my knowledge and experience in C and Haskel isn't really broad at all.

Comment: If this is anything other than a project to learn C#, please don't store credentials in plaintext on disk. Use a real, secure authentication mechanism.

Comment: no, this is university work, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your Registo class should know how to load itself from a text file and save itself to a text file. For simplicity I'll show how to make a tab separated file:

```
class Registo
{
    public List<Tech> ListaTechs { get; set; }
    public Registo()
    {
        ListaTechs = new List<Tech>();
    }
    public void AddTech(Tech tech)
    {
        ListaTechs.Add(tech);
    }

    public void Load(string filePath){
      foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath)){
        var bits = line.Split('\t');
        if(bits.Length != 3) continue;

        var tech = new Tech(bits[0], bits[1], bits[2]); //assume you save like nameTABidTABkey

        AddTech(tech);
      }
    } 

    public void Save(string filePath){
      var sb = new StringBuilder();

      foreach(var tech in ListaTechs)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\r\n", tech.TechName, tech.TechId, tech.AccessKey);

      File.WriteAllText(sb.ToString(), filePath);
    } 
}
```

It adds a couple of methods that let a Registo load/save itself from/to some given path. Registo defines the format it will save so that it can load itself again via the same format

Now we can load techs from disk, search them for an AccessKey:

```
var reg = new Registo();
reg.Load(@"C:\registo.txt");

var accessKey = "the key you are searching for";
var tech = reg.ListaTechs.FirstOrDefault(t => t.AccessKey == accessKey);
```

You'd probably encapsulate this final line as a new method in Registo, perhaps called `FindByAccessKey(string accessKey)`

For FirstOrDefault to work you'll need to `using System.Linq` and you should use the fact that `null` will be returned if there is no tech with the given access key.. Oh, and that comparison is case sensitive

---

A few notes on styling your code:

- In C# methods and properties are `NamedLikeThis` i.e. PascalCase, parameters to methods are `namedLikeThis` i.e. camelCase, and we use plurals for collections (`ListaTechs`).
- Generally the get/set for a property go on the same line as the prop name if they are empty; put them on new lines if they have a body

Comment: Thank you for your input! How does your Save differ from my saveRegistry? Besides being inside the class

Comment: Please do not put code in comments; the formatting is awful

Comment: Well, it a) only saves a file (your save seems to load?), and it saves it as a text file - binary formatter won't :).. Personally I would make a workflow like "load" then "add to" then "save", rather than making a "save" actually do an "append" ..

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and extra pointers!

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but the 4 lines of code in the smaller block belong within the method FindByAccessKey(string accessKey) that's in the Registo right?

Comment: It depends on how you want to do things, but I'd say "no" - it was not my intent that those 4 lines would be the "FindByAccessKey" - only the final line would be "find by accesskey" as it is the only line that implements a find operation. The first two lines load the registo, and the third line simply declares an example parameter, which would be the `string accessKey` in  method signature like `FindByAccessKey(string accessKey)`. I would imagine that your program would load a registo as a one time operation when it starts, but it would repeatedly FindByAccessKey when running, hence why I ...

Comment: ..wouldn't expect the file to be loaded from disk every time the find occurs. Don't forget that the Load operation as written doesn't clear the existing data, so if you did have a Find op that loaded the same file again and again, by the time you've searched your 10 entries a hundred times your registo has a thousand things in its list

Comment: Ok, I will try to make it work like that :) thank you once again